# Changing only the coding scheme of a factor changes whether an LME will converge or not - why is this?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, categorical-encoding

I'm trying to fit a rather complex LME in R. It has three binary predictors (cong, precong, and sex), a categorical variable with 4 levels (age group - grs), and a continuous predictor (trial_cent, this is the trial number centered on the trial in the middle). Observations are nested within participants - there are 108 participants, at least 25 in each age group, and around 290 observations per participant.

First, I used simple dummy coding with 0s and 1s for the factor variables, and I got the following model to converge nicely. (The model might look peculiar but I got to it by reducing a full model step by step.)

```
dummy_model <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + cong*precong*grs + cong*sex + grs*trial_cent + (1+cong*precong|subject), 
              data = Data, verbose = 0, REML = F)
```

This converges without an issue, and gives completely plausible results.

Then I realized I should probably use effect coding instead of simple dummy coding because of the presence of interactions, and because that would make the interpretation of the coefficients more straightforward. So I did this:

```
contrasts(Data$cong) <- contr.sum
contrasts(Data$precong) <- contr.sum
contrasts(Data$sex) <- contr.sum

Data$grs <- factor(Data$grs,levels(Data$grs)[c(2:4, 1)]) #this was just to make sure that the last category is the one I want to use as reference
contrasts(Data$grs) <- contr.sum
```

Now I went back and ran the *exact same* model, but now it failed to converge.

I tried using different optimizers, like this:

```
effect_model <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + cong*precong*grs + cong*sex + grs*trial_cent + (1+cong*precong|subject), 
          data = Data, verbose = 0, REML = F, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

(And then replacing "bobyqa" with "Nelder_Mead" and - via optimx - with "nlminb" and "L-BFGS-B".)

With every variant I got a convergence warning. Most of them cited a degenerate Hessian with negative eigenvalue as the reason, while "nlminb" gave the following: "Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00268248 (tol = 0.002, component 1)".
I also tried to restart from a previous fit, as suggested here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html - but that didn't work either.

Interestingly, more complex models - with more variables / interactions - converge with no problem. (And every model converges with dummy coding.)

My question is: why would the coding scheme affect whether a model converges or not? Did I do something wrong at the re-coding stage? Is it not doing what I assumed it should be?

(Note: I found a very similar question on Stack Overflow from two years ago, with no answer/solution. I thought it might be a better fit here.)

Comment: `lme4` is known to sometimes give false positive warnings, see `help('convergence')`. Are the fits (i.e., the log-likelihood) actually different with different contrasts?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the AIC, BIC, LL, and deviance values are slightly different (within about .3 of each other). (However, this only seems to be the case when I use the default optimizier. When I use nlminb for the effect coded model, I get the same values as for the dummy coded one, for which I used the default...!)

Comment: So, use `nlminb`. Problem solved.

Comment: Well, it still doesn't converge - or at least I still get a warning message - with nlminb, it's just that the model fit itself seems identical to the dummy coded, default optimizer model. If those values are the same, do you think it's safe to use coefficients from that (i.e., the failed) model?

Comment: Have you read the documentation linked to in my first comment? Checking convergence is a non-trivial task and a convergence warning doesn't necessarily mean non-convergence.

Comment: (Additionally, when I run Anova() on the models - dummy coded default vs effect coded nlminb -, the Chisq values are *almost* identical, but differ in some decimal places. I would have thought they should be identical.)

Comment: Sorry I sent my previous comment at the exact same time you did yours. I checked the documentation, and I think I'm in the clear: "if all optimizers converge to values that are practically equivalent, then we would consider the convergence warnings to be false positives" - I suspect this means the logLik and deviance values, and those are very similar with every optimizer.